# Edit Table of Contents in Preview?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

In Preview, is there a way to change/edit the names of links in the Table of Contents of a pdf?

Answer (score 8):

You could use a combination of tools to remove the old ToC, and attach a new one:

- use [PDF SAM](http://www.pdfsam.org/) ("**s**plit **a**nd **m**erge"; it's FOSS and cross-platform) to take off the old ToC;
- use [PDF Outliner](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdfoutliner/id420874236?mt=12) ($4.99 in Mac App store) to generate a new one.

<sub>See other helpful tools [in another Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13929/136150).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Preview does not support this.

You need more advanced PDF editing software, like Adobe Acrobat Pro or [PDF Outliner](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdfoutliner/id420874236?mt=12).

Answer (score 4):

Preview can't modify or add TOC, but I find an alternative way to do this is use bookmark.

Just navigate to the page and press CMD+D, or choose "Tools/Add Bookmark" menu item, the page number and some text from the begin of the page will show on the bookmark view.

I use this way to add link to the PDF file without TOC, and it works.

Comment: It should be pointed out that Preview's Bookmarks are not part of the PDF specification, and do not appear in other PDF readers.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as has stated by others, preview cannot edit toc.

I tried PDF SAM. To be honest, I think it's a bit user-unfriendly.

Give it a try on Foxit Reader, free and elegant as on Windows platform, as shown below.

[image: Foxit Reader TOC Edit Sample]

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around is to add an outline to the pdf using the iPhone version of the (free) *Documents* app ([Readdle](https://readdle.com/documents)). The table of contents can then be seen in the *Preview* app (and probably any other pdf viewer).

An advantage to this method is that outline entries may be placed into submenus. A disadvantage is that you need to go to each point in the document one time and enter the needed text on a phone. But since I only want a dozen or so outline items I find this doesn't take much time, especially since voice dictation works so well.