# Can I edit/create a PDF's Table of Contents with freeware?

Tags: terminal, software-recommendation, pdf, unix, preview

I have a PDF with a number of parts. I would like to create a Table of Contents to navigate the PDF with ease. I would like to do on a Mac this with freeware. (A command-line program would be great.)

Is that possible? Similar questions have been [asked before](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202337/edit-table-of-contents-in-preview?newreg=b0c5d121993c4ba08245400880e7639a), but as far as I can tell, the best answer given has been [PDFOutliner](http://www.onekerato.com/downloads.html), which is not freeware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [PDFtk Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) and [Coherent PDF Command Line Tools](http://community.coherentpdf.com) have a wide range of PDF command line utilities.

I've used both tools on and off, but never needed to do any TOC work. The Bookmarks section in Coherent's [Usage Examples Page](http://www.coherentpdf.com/usage-examples.html#6) looks like it may be an approach to experiment with:

**6. Bookmarks**

`cpdf -list-bookmarks in.pdf`

List the bookmarks in in.pdf. This would produce:

```
0 "Part 1" 1 open
1 "Part 1A" 2
2 "Part 1B" 3
0 "Part 2" 4
1 "Part 2a" 5
```

`cpdf -add-bookmarks bookmarks.txt in.pdf -o out.pdf`

Add bookmarks in the same form from a prepared file bookmarks.txt to in.pdf, writing to out.pdf.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Since `cpdf -add-bookmarks` overwrites the old table of contents of the PDF, it seems to edit the bookmarks using `cpdf`, the way to go is: (1) `cpdf -list-bookmarks in.pdf > out.txt`; (2) edit `out.txt`; (3) `cpdf -add-bookmarks...`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python script that will run on MacOS to produce a rudimentary TOC.
You'll need to enter your own values for the input file and output filename, and the page number and label for each entry.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# CREATE PDF OUTLINES v.1.0 : Add a simple list of Bookmarks to a PDF.

from Foundation import  NSURL, NSString
import Quartz as Quartz
import sys

# You will need to change these filepaths to a local test pdf and an output file.
infile = "/path/to/file.pdf"
outfile = '/path/to/output.pdf'

def getOutline(page, label):
    myPage = myPDF.pageAtIndex_(page)
    pageSize = myPage.boundsForBox_(Quartz.kCGPDFMediaBox)
    x = 0
    y = Quartz.CGRectGetMaxY(pageSize)
    pagePoint = Quartz.CGPointMake(x,y)
    myDestination = Quartz.PDFDestination.alloc().initWithPage_atPoint_(myPage, pagePoint)
    myLabel = NSString.stringWithString_(label)
    myOutline = Quartz.PDFOutline.alloc().init()
    myOutline.setLabel_(myLabel)
    myOutline.setDestination_(myDestination)
    return myOutline

pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(infile)
myPDF = Quartz.PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)
if myPDF:
    # Create Outlines. Add the Page Index (from 0) and label in pairs here:
    myTableOfContents = [
        (0, 'Page 1'), 
        (1, 'Page 2'),
        (2, 'Page 3')
        ]
    allMyOutlines = []
    for index, outline in myTableOfContents:
        allMyOutlines.append(getOutline(index, outline))

    rootOutline = Quartz.PDFOutline.alloc().init()
    for index, value in enumerate(allMyOutlines):
        rootOutline.insertChild_atIndex_(value, index)
    myPDF.setOutlineRoot_(rootOutline)
    myPDF.writeToFile_(outfile)
```